# Why does $a+b+c=3\;$ imply $\;a\sqrt{a+3} + b\sqrt{b+3} + c\sqrt{c+3} \ge 6$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=3$.
Prove that      $$a\sqrt{a+3} + b\sqrt{b+3} + c\sqrt{c+3} \geqslant 6$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the AMGM inequality theorem that would state that $a+b+c \ge 3\sqrt{abc}$?

Comment: ... and that $a\sqrt{a+3} + b\sqrt{b+3}+ c\sqrt{b+3} \ge 3\sqrt{abc\sqrt{(a+3)(b+3)(c+3)}}$?

Comment: Could you show us your work before having posted your question here?  That's kind of the point:  we are here to *help* (advise, hint, suggest, get you started, not to *do someone's work for them.*

Comment: Please anyone trying to edit the title, we need words in the title that **do not appear in a hyperlinked/mathjaxed expressions.

Comment: Why are bare problem statements/homework, tagged as inequalities, not addressed like such problems posted in other tags.  Lack of context is lack of context, whatever the tag.  The asker simply demands us to work on his/her behalf, given some statement, "prove that .... .... "  after which, it seems, trigger-happy beavers jump in to oblige/cater to the asker's demand(s)

Comment: I can't solve this inequality. Maybe there is someone who will help me or  at least will guide me. thanks in advance)

Comment: Leo. You haven't addressed the question: Please add to your post (click on "edit") your answer to $W-h-a-t \quad d-i-d \quad y-o-u \quad t-r-y$?

Comment: you means that what have i done for solution of this?

Comment: ok now i understood

Comment: I think you may have mis-understood me, or perhaps I wasn't clear.  I am asking you to include a summary of what you have tried.  It's understandable that you may be stuck; it just helps us, to help you, when you include a summary of your own attempts to solve the problem, even if you got stuck, or are unable to move on.

Comment: If a+b+c = 3. Then one of them must be greater equal than 1. So a>=1 a+3>=4 √(a+3)>=2 a√(a+3)>=2a . Then b√(b+3) + c√(c+3) >=4.  That's all

Comment: Can you help me with my way please? If you can

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(x) = x\sqrt{x +3}$ is convex over $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, hence by Jensen's inequality we have:

$\Rightarrow f\left(\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}\right)\leq \dfrac{f(a) +f(b)+f(c)}{3}$

$\Rightarrow 6 \leq a\sqrt{a+3} +b\sqrt{b+3} +c\sqrt{c+3}$, as required

Comment: Talking about convex functions goes way beyond pre-calculus, according to the OP's tag...

Comment: @loki123 in all fairness, so does finding the minimum of the function in your answer...

Comment: Actually, the tag "algebra-precalculus" was added by an earlier editor, not by the asker.

Answer (score 1):

First set up a function $$f(a,b,c)=\sqrt{a+3} a+\sqrt{b+3} b+\sqrt{c+3} c.$$ Then, set $a=3-b-c$ to eliminate $a$ and get:
$$f(b,c)=-\sqrt{-b-c+6} (b+c-3)+\sqrt{b+3} b+c \sqrt{c+3},$$ then find the minimum of the function $f(b,c)$, which is $f(b=1,c=1)=6$. Therefore, we have $$f \ge 6$$ as requested.